# Security token has really expired and shall be discarded !!!! (lifetime is = 60000 )

Tags: node-opcua

I have the problem that my node-red opc client does not get new data after some days. I use node-opcua as a server and create a subscription to some variables. After some time (about 2 days) the server outputs the following message.

```
Security token has really expired and shall be discarded !!!! (lifetime is =  60000 )
 Server will now refuse message with token  4531
```

Can u help me to solve this problem

Thanks